# What upper bounds be given on $\theta$ such that in Mitchell's model $L{\cal U}]$, $Pow(\kappa)\subseteq L_\theta[{\cal U}]$?

Tags: set-theory

It is proved that GCH holds in $L[{\cal U}]$ in
 [https://doi.org/10.2307/2272343](http://doi.org/10.2307/2272343).
A refinement of the question asks what upper bounds be given on
$\theta$ such that in $L{\cal U}]$, $Pow(\kappa)\subseteq L_\theta[{\cal U}]$?

By condensation, in $L$ $\theta$ can be bounded by $\kappa^+$.
In $L[U]$ for $U$ a measure on $\mu$, the proof of theorem 19.3 of
Jech's set theory book shows that $\theta$ can be bounded by
$\max(\kappa^+,\mu^+)$.  It is also of interest whether this bound
can be improved.

Answer (score 2):

For $\kappa \geq \mu$, the bound $\kappa^+$ is best possible. For $\kappa < \mu$,
$\theta$ is an ordinal less than $\mu^+$ of cofinality $\kappa^+$, and the function which sends $\kappa$ to its $\theta$ is monotone.

Comment: This only yields $|\theta|=\mu$, at least using the method in Jech.  I just noticed that Wylie's thesis "Condensation and Square in a Higher Core Models" might yield $\kappa^{++}$, even for $L[{\cal U}]$ where ${\cal U}$ has order 0 ultrafilters.